# Adding Custom .js file to Wordpress as a Background

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have been given the .js files to create this vignette effect.

https://demo.projectwyvern.com/

I cannot for the life of me get the file to work on my homepage. I am using the Theme Astra and the elementor page builder.

I would like the .js to work as a background and for elementor to call the js.

I have tried many ways including adding the .js into the header, but all I got was a load of code on the page. I have been told by the creator 'to put a div element with id '#container' on the page.'

I've also tried a few custom code plugins. I feel like I need to use the enqueue script in the functions.php?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the files given to be by the creator can be found on his github.

https://github.com/ProjectWyvern/wyvern-logo-effects

Comment: What do you mean by "the .js to work as a background"?

Comment: The Javascript file is an image effect that vignettes the image. I would like the javascript to work behind other text and buttons on my site.

Comment: "The javascript" won't work in the background, its the action your javascript performs that changes some classes or inline styles. So, what have you tried so far? Putting a `<div id="container">` in your markup is not that hard

Comment: I am using a Page Builder called Elementor at the moment. Should I add it the ID to the CSS ID option of the image? I'm not even sure I have the .js added to my site correctly.

Comment: I have tried to add the .js via the enqueue function in the functions.php . How will I know that the .js is working at ready to be added to an object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the header.php template for your theme (you should probably create a child theme and alter that).

Per the example at that github project:

Add something like this to the header.php

```
<div id="container"></div>
<img src="static/logo.svg" id="logo" style="display: none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
```

Then, make a javascript file with code like this, which is what activates your effect:

```html
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.id = 'canvas';
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(canvas);
  var seriously = new Seriously();
  var logo = seriously.source('#logo');
  var target = seriously.target('#canvas');
  var vignette = seriously.effect('vignette');
  vignette.amount = 1;
  vignette.source = logo;
  var mask = seriously.transform();
  mask.source = vignette;
  target.source = mask;
  var factor = 1;
  var diff = 0; 
  function setPosition(x, y) {
    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvas.offsetTop;
    var xd = Math.abs(x - (canvas.width / 2)) / canvas.width;
    var yd = Math.abs(y - (canvas.height / 2)) / canvas.height;
    diff = xd + yd;
  }
  function mouseMove(e) { setPosition(e.pageX, e.pageY); } 
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  var amt = 0.5;  
  var del = 200;
  mouseMove({pageX: 0, pageY: 0})
  seriously.go(function(now) {
    factor = amt + (Math.sin(now / del) / Math.PI / 8);
    vignette.amount = factor * 100 * diff;
  });
```

Next, save serious.js and your new javascript file into theme's scripts directory

```
[astratheme-child]/scripts/seriously.js
[astratheme-child]/scripts/activateseriously.js
```

Then, in functions.php file, enqueue the two javascript files:

```
wp_enqueue_script('seriously', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/seriously.js');
wp_enqueue_script('seriously', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/activateseriously.js');
```

If you have trouble with it trying to run before the page loads all the way, remove the enqueue calls from functions.php, and instead add the two scripts as tags in the footer.php.

Comment: Ok, I have done this. What would I now need to do to call the .js for a particular object? And how would I know the .js is running on the page? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The custom script file you created should do all the calling itself.  The id of the div you added to the header.php is later used in the custom script to tell the script which elements to work on.  See the lines starting with 'var logo' and 'var target.'

After you added all that, what problem are you having?  Does it just not do anything?

Comment: Nope, Nothing was happening. I then changed the header img src to the actual image I was using as the .svg file is not on my library and still nothing. Is the #canvas specifically for elementor, if so I think I've changed that.

Comment: The canvas element is what's used to draw the vignetted image, I expect.  You can change its id if you need to, but you need to make sure that when you you change the id in the 'var target =...' line too.

Are you getting any messages in the javascript console?

Comment: `frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:408 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at cbpHorizontalSlideOutMenu._init (frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:408)
    at new cbpHorizontalSlideOutMenu (frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:398)
    at frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:499
    at frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:501
    at frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:503
_init @ frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:408
cbpHorizontalSlideOutMenu @ frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:398
(anonymous) @ frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:499
(anonymous) @ frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:501
(anonymous) @ frontend.min.js?ver=1.1.2:503`

Comment: Does that error go away if you remove the two javascripts you added?

Comment: No it doesn't... So that's not the problem. With the functions you provided I just copied them straight into the function.php. Do I need to add some code before them to get them to work?

Comment: Shall I try and add the enqueue functions to the footer instead? Looking at the Javascript console it doesn't look like the functions are running.

Comment: I have just realised why it wasn't working. I have a custom header plugin for elementor. I assume the code we put in doesn't work as the header doesn't appear?

Comment: I'm not familiar with elementor, but if you're doing something that keeps the header from appearing, it likely won't work.  You can maybe fix this by moving the HTML tags to one of the templates that does get used.

Comment: If you look at the site in the web console. Can you see the scripts working? Also how would I change the code to work with elements that I assign a specific CSS ID to?

Comment: Most browsers have a javascript debugger that you can use to insert breakpoints to check on what it's doing.  

If you look in the code, the places where it assigns something like '#logo' to one of the 'seriously' object's properites are where it's actually using the ID values.

Comment: Would you be able to come on a discord chat with me to try and talk through the issue. I've been trying so long on this issue that I would be willing to pay a little bit for your time if we can get it working.

Comment: I'm apparently locked out of my discord account immediately, but I might be able to this evening or over the weekend.  Is there any chance you can post a link to the actual site in question, or a copy of it?

Also, I just noticed a mistake I made in my original post; you need to change this line:

    wp_enqueue_script('seriously', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/activateseriously.js')

to this: 
wp_enqueue_script('activateseriously', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/activateseriously.js')

Comment: Thanks. For your help Aaron but I think its more or less sorted out. Thanks again.